# Dictionary values from a list of keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

and a list:

```
l = ['a', 'c']
```

How do I obtain a list of the dictionary values from the list above? i.e. I want:

```
[1, 3]
```

I've tried:

```
d[l]
```

but get the following error: **TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'**.

Comment: I searched for ages. Why isn't this easier to find?!

Comment: @cs95 I googled "list of dictionary values from list of keys python" it was the first result

Answer (score 1):

You can do [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
values = [d[x] for x in l]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[d[key] for key in l]
```

Python itself doesn't do vectorized expressions like the one you tried.

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprheension:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
l = ['a', 'c']
res = [d[key] for key in l]
```